# many small sized functions

Tags: c, optimization, compiler-construction

in computer literature it is generally recommended to write short functions as much as possible. I understand it may increase readability (although not always), and such approach also provides more flexibility. But does it have something to do with optimization as well? I mean -- does it matter to a compiler to compile a bunch of small routines rather than a few large routines?

Thanks.

Comment: Aside from optimization concerns, it's a simple matter of writing *correct* C: Since C does not support multiple exits natively, writing small functions is almost *necessary* to allow the authors to reason about how the code branches and at which point allocated resources need to be freed.

Comment: @Kerrek SB -- I'm curious about your statement 'C does not support multiple exits natively'. Do you mean that you can only call exit() in a single place within the source?

Comment: @BartonChittenden: No. What I mean is easiest explained by comparing C to C++, which *does* support arbitrary exits via destructors, i.e. code that is always executed when a scope is left. This is crucial to local resource management (i.e. only touching one piece of code to change one unit of logic), and to be able to reason about your code's behaviour. The only generic way to write correct C in a vaguely manageable fashion is with lots of `goto`s, or alternatively with very small functions whose exits you can inspect manually.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Ok, that makes sense. There is atexit(), of course, but that only works at a global level...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends on the compiler. Many older compilers only optimized a single function at a time, so writing larger functions (up to to some limit) could improve optimization -- but (with most of them) exceeding that limit turned optimization off completely.

Most reasonably current compilers can generate inline code for functions (and C99 added the `ineline` keyword to facilitate that) and do global (cross-function) optimization, in which case it normally makes no difference at all.

Comment: +1 for mentioning inlining. You may want to mention that with C99 inlining in C became official.

Answer (score 1):

@twain249 and @Jerry are both correct; breaking a program into multiple functions can have a negative effect on performance, but it depends on whether or not the compiler can optimize the functions into inline code.

The only way to know for sure is to examine the assembler output of your program and do some profiling.  For example, if you know a particular code path is causing a performance problem, you can look at the assembler, and see how many functions are getting called, how many times parameters are being pushed onto the stack, etc.  In that case, you may want to consolidate small functions into one larger one.

This has been a concern for me in the past: doing very tight optimization for embedded projects, I have consciously tried to reduce the number of function calls, especially in tight loops.  However, this does produce ungainly functions, sometimes several pages long.  To mitigate the maintenance cost of this, you can use macros, which I have leveraged heavily and successfully to make sure there are no function calls while at the same time preserving readability.